# Slick 3.1.x How to implement a Many-to-Many join?

Tags: scala, slick

In the `UserDao` I'm trying to define a method that given a user will get all the security roles assigned to it. This is a many-to-many relationship, here the pseudo database design ([here is the actual Tables.scala full generated implementation](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala/blob/master/app/generated/Tables.scala)):

```
User(PK id)
SecurityRole(PK id)
UserSecurityRole(
  userId FK to User(id), 
  securityRoleId FK to SecurityRole(id)
)
```

Therefore I try defining my `getRoles` function like this:

```
def getRoles(user: UserRow) : Future[List[SecurityRoleRow]] = {
  val action = for {
  role <- SecurityRole join UserSecurityRole on (_.id === _.securityRoleId) 
            join User on (_.userId === _.id)
  } yield role
  db.run(action)
}
```

or like this:

```
def getRoles(user: UserRow) : Future[List[SecurityRoleRow]] = {
  val action = for {
    role <- SecurityRole join (UserSecurityRole join User on (_.userId === _.id)) on (_.id === _.securityRoleId)
  } yield role
  db.run(action)
}
```

but in both cases I get the compiler error that `can not resolve symbol _.userId` note that the output has to be a `Role` and thus, I start both alternatives with a `SecurityRole` because that's what I need to get. My impression is that after it does the first join, some columns are wiped out, or?

In SQL this would be as simple as:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM SecurityRole t1, 
     UserSecurityRole t2,
     User t3
WHERE t1.id = t2.securityRoleId
  AND t3.id = t2.userId
```

that's it. Then if I wanted slickifying this SQL into my `UserDao` I could do:

```
def getRoles(user: UserRow) : Future[List[SecurityRoleRow]] = {
  val action = sql"""SELECT t1.* " +
                    "FROM SecurityRole t1, " + 
                         "UserSecurityRole t2, " +
                    "WHERE t1.id = t2.securityRoleId " +
                      "AND ${user.id} = t2.userId""".as[SecurityRoleRow]
    db.run(action)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically right (well, kind of, they are not wiped out but rather tuple gets extended). Instead of this:

```
def getRoles(user: UserRow) : Future[List[SecurityRoleRow]] = {
  val action = for {
  role <- SecurityRole join UserSecurityRole on (_.id === _.securityRoleId) 
            join User on (_.userId === _.id)
  } yield role
  db.run(action)
}
```

(btw you forgot about `result` call I believe)

you should use:

```
def getRoles(user: UserRow) : Future[List[SecurityRoleRow]] = {
  val action = (for {
  role <- SecurityRole join UserSecurityRole on (_.id === _.securityRoleId) 
            join User on (_._2.userId === _.id) // here is the change!!
  } yield role).result
  db.run(action)
}
```

**Each new join adds new nested tuple**. Look at this slide from my presentation here (I deconstruct this tuple each type with pattern matching but's it's all the same): http://slides.com/pdolega/slick-101#/75 (and especially - take a look at the next slide which makes it all neater by using foreign key; in your case that would be perfect solution).

EDIT:

Even without defining foreign keys (which I think you should) you can change your version to monadic form, which avoids all the tuple nesting:

```
val action = (for {
  role <- SecurityRole 
  userRole <- UserSecurityRole if role.id === userRole.securityRoleId 
  user <- User if userRole.userId === user.id
} yield role).result

db.run(action)
```

Comment: @giovanni-azua basically I advice you to take a look at the presentation and associated repo. It's meant to be a kind of fast introduction to basics for Slick 3.x. In resource section you also have a link to recording of extremely good workshop run by Dave Gurnell ( https://vimeo.com/148074461 )

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! How does performance compare using pure slick to the SQL version? I will find how to get the generated SQL to get an idea. Many thanks!

Comment: You have generated SQLs on the slides I linked. Also to see easily what's generated simply add this set of loggers to your `logback.xml`:
`<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.benchmark" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.parameter" level="DEBUG" />`